# Generally, which instrument make more volume between piano and violin

Tags: piano, violin

Generally, if we play at the same way, the same music, with the same nuances, which instrument make more volume between the piano or the violin ?

Comment: This is an ill-defined question. “With the same nuances” doesn't make sense, because piano and violin are played in fundamentally different ways.

Answer (score 1):

A piano. It weighs more, has tighter strings, heavier strings, burns longer, etc. The following chart makes come comparisons.

https://www.gcaudio.com/tips-tricks/decibel-loudness-comparison-chart/

One thing I don't know is if the chart compares a single violin note against a two octave chord on the piano or just single notes.

However, loudness isn't the only issue in composition. Violins, due to agility and attack, can be heard over an orchestra. So can a harp if playing a glissando. I don't think a lute can be heard over bagpipe though. The timbre and style a of a melodic line may make the instrument heard even with loud background. Bass drums put out lots of energy per beat but it's not sustained so can't really swamp the band.

Comment: "burns longer" what? Is this a joke or an actual thing?

Comment: It's both. There are old jokes about the difference between a flute and a piano or similar. Also, the size of the instrument affects the volume. Big objects can move more air. (I put these in for emphasis. In instrumental, all other things being equal, size matters.)